# Chrome 28 App, getUserMedia PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, google-chrome-app

I'm facing an issue with chrome 28.

I build an application that use the webcam to take picture.

I had no problem with it, but since I upgrade to chrome 28, my application is not working anymore (I'm getting an error with the getUserMedia function).

Here is the message : `{"constraintName":"","message":"","name":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}.`

If I try to run the app code on a simple `html` and `httpserver`, I got no problem with it.

And when using the APP I'm not asked anymore if I allow the usage of the webcam.

I've tried to turn on some chrome flags for webrtc but nothing change.

Does anybody has/had this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: I have this same problem. If I run the same application with Firefox it runs. I then also make sure the camera is not being used by any other app (i.e. I close firefox and restart Chrome) (I have also logged out from my user), I try again and I keep receiving the same Permission denied error. Firefox is able to display the app correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally denied access to the webcam in the past. If your site is being served via HTTPS, that setting will be saved. [This page](https://vline.com/developer/docs/debugging#get_local_stream_failed) has a description of that error and a screenshot that shows what the settings should look like.

Comment: I checked if I didn't deny the camera access but there isn't any blocked website.
I'am not using http/https, the code I'm running is in a Chrome APP.
I tried to use it on chrome 27 and I got no problem with the same code.
Does someone has the same issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure to give permissions in your Chrome application?

Comment: Specifically, you'll want to add "audioCapture" and "videoCapture" to your manifest: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions.html

Comment: Hi, thanks but I allready tried with the persmissions and the I still have the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have tried all the above:

- Make sure that there is no other program or browser tab accessing the camera.
- If you are on Android, open a camera App to make sure that the it's not stuck (it happens to me all the time with Cyanogen).

What the browser is reporting is that a media source is missing (might be permissions, config or harware). More info here: http://webrtchacks.com/getusermedia/

Answer (score 0):

Once you have made sure that the site is not blocked in Privacy content settings, Goto chrome://flags/#enable-permissions-bubbles in Chrome and ENable these . Now the notification will appear asking for permission to access the web cam , just click allow  .

Comment: I would say that is not a _proper_ solution since nobody can expect users to do that.. But I'm not voting on that.